# Declaring Global Structs Containing Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm using a separate GUI program that creates .c & .h files. I'm trying to create a structure using these pre-existing variables. The best solution I have found so far is to create a structure of pointers, and then assign the address of the pre-existing variables to those struct members.

However, since I need to access this structure in several different functions, the only way I've found is to define these structures globally. (I cannot change the function parameters.) This inevitably leads to pointers (struct members) being defined globally. This does work consistently, but I know it is bad practice. Is there any other way to achieve this?

edit:
Basically, I need a way to use pre-existing variables when creating a structure. I have a structure for a slider, and include pointers to different variables (slider length, percentage,etc.).

```
void UpdateSlider(SLIDER_TEMPLATE * pSliderStruct, uint16_t XTouchValue, uint16_t YTouchValue)
{
    int16_t SliderStart = (pSliderStruct->origin) + (pSliderStruct->handle_size / 2);
    int16_t SliderEnd = (pSliderStruct->length) + (pSliderStruct->origin) - ((pSliderStruct->handle_size) / 2);
    int16_t SliderUsableLength = (pSliderStruct->length) - pSliderStruct->handle_size;
    int16_t TempSliderLevel;
    int16_t TempSliderPercent;
    uint8_t SliderFivePercent = SliderUsableLength / 20;


    if ((XTouchValue <= SliderEnd) && (XTouchValue >= SliderStart) && (YTouchValue <= 760) && (YTouchValue >= 400) )
    {
        TempSliderLevel =  (XTouchValue - (pSliderStruct->origin));
        TempSliderPercent = (int)((*pSliderStruct->level - (pSliderStruct->handle_size / 2))  / ((float)SliderUsableLength / 100) );
        *pSliderStruct->level =  ROUND_TO_NEAREST(TempSliderLevel, SliderFivePercent);
        *pSliderStruct->percentage = ROUND_TO_NEAREST(TempSliderPercent,5);
    }
}
```

declaration in header file:

```
typedef const struct {
 int16_t origin;
 int16_t length;
 int16_t * level;
 uint8_t * percentage;
 uint8_t handle_size;
}SLIDER_TEMPLATE;

void UpdateSlider(SLIDER_TEMPLATE * pSliderStruct, uint16_t XTouchValue, uint16_t YTouchValue);
```

Used in several functions like:

```
void UpdateVars( GUI_DATA_STRUCT* GuiData )
{

    if (ACTIVE_VSWITCH == 5005)
    {
        UpdateSlider( &Slider4, X_TOUCH_VALUE, Y_TOUCH_VALUE);
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Your description is very confusing and unclear. Please show a clear and complete code example that illustrates your problem. For example, "I'm using a separate GUI program that compiles into .c & .h files". It isn't clear what that means. Other files don't "compiles into" C and H files. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There are many ways to pass variables around. But without more context of what you are trying to do and your existing code structure it is difficult to answer what you are really trying to ask.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This inevitably leads to pointers (struct members) being defined globally. This does work consistently, but I know it is bad practice. Is there any other way to achieve this?

If you need access to those variables inside a function and you can't change the function arguments to add those variables, the only way to get access to the variables is by declaring them as global variables.

If possible you can declare them static within a compilation unit so that they are not available to other compilation units.

So in short: With the restrictions given, the only solution is to use globals.